# How to ignore all hidden directories/files recursively in a git repository?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'd like to have Git ignore all hidden files and directories. 
i.e.

- `.aptitude`
- `.ssh/`
- `.bash_rc`
- `config/.hidden`

Is there a simple rule to cover this without specifically adding each entry?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Just add a pattern to `.gitignore`

```
.*
!/.gitignore
```

**Edit:** Added the `.gitignore` file itself (matters if it is not yet commited).

Comment: You might want to force-add some files that are necessary after this. eg. the .htaccess file. Based on your requirements of course.

Comment: @dakdad: Thanks for the suggestion. Improved the answer. If Poe has some special files like `.htaccess` already checked in they keep being followed. `gitignore` is only important for new files.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer Maybe this is getting off the subject, but is there a reason for un-ignoring only `/.gitignore` and not every `.gitignore` file regardless of where it is located? I.e. why not list `!.gitignore` (no slash)?

Comment: @JasonYoung Interesting question. Well, this pattern un-ignores just the file itself. I find this more concise with no side effects for an example to copy & paste. Of course, you can probably just un-ignore any `.gitignore` files in your top-level `.gitignore` file. But that choice is up to you.

Comment: if you want just hidden files within root user just use this line `/.*`

Answer (score 79):

**.gitignore** will only effect files that haven't been 'added' already.

To make new .gitignore entries affect all files

1. Make changes to .gitignore
2. `git commit -a -m "Pre .gitignore changes"`
3. `git rm -r --cached .`
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -a -m "Post .gitignore changes"`
6. `git status`
   should output "nothing to commit (working directory clean)"
   `

Comment: The line "haven't been 'added' already" is the key here, because if you already commited a given file the ignore will not work on him anymore you must delete it from the repository and the next time you create it the .gitignore will ignore it.

Answer (score 27):

In `.git/info/exclude`, add this line:

```
.*
```

This will make ignoring all hidden/dot files recursively the default for every repository on the machine. A separate `.gitignore` file for every repo is not needed this way.

Answer (score 1):

For me `.*` didn't work, doesn't ignore e.g. `notebooks/templates/.ipynb_checkpoints/`. What did work is:

```
/**/.*  # ignore all dotted files
/**/.*/ # ignore all dotted folders
!/.gitignore  # except `gitignore` :)
```