# Can't exclude a folder using .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I can't exclude files from `.idea` folder from tracking by git. It is on the same level as `.gitignore` file and my `.gitignore` contains:

```
.idea
```

and even:

```
idea
```

Any advice guys?

Comment: Is it already checked in? Read the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021441/gitignore-hidden-dot-directories

Comment: that's hilarious. I googled this and it's the same folder I'm trying to ignore

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Append a slash to exclude directories.

```
.idea/
```

Comment: still see files in this folder with 'git status'

Comment: If the files have already been committed or added to the index, you'll need to also remove them from git `git rm --cached .idea/**/*`. Commit that and you should be all set.

Comment: Maybe due to version change, seems that the command should be `git rm -r --cached <dir to be removed>`