# Git Ignore a directory that begins with a '.'

Tags: git

I have a folder called `.tmp`.

In my `.gitignore` file, I am trying to exclude everything in it.

I have tried `.tmp`, `.tmp/*/`, etc.

I believe this is because it is looking for a file with a `.tmp` extension. Is there a way to define that this is a directory and not an extension?

Comment: `/.tmp` or `/.tmp/` ought to work for top-level directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: how to ignore hidden directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021441/git-how-to-ignore-hidden-directories)

Comment: Could you post your exact `.gitignore` file (or one that reproduces the same issue)? Also, can you recreate this issue in another git repo?

Answer (score 1):

```
.tmp
```

in .gitignore should work fine.

.tmp won't get commited to git as long as you don't use "git add --force"

If you want to have .tmp folder, but no file commited to it, just write this in .tmp/.gitignore :

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Comment: ".tmp won't get commited at all to git." --- it won't be shown in the status or staged. But it does not affect comitting at all.

Comment: Interesting comment. Can `.tmp` be commited without being staged?

Comment: You can stage it and commit. Being ignored does not mean you cannot stage and commit it.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to type `git add -f .tmp`?

Comment: Yes, you would. My initial point is ".tmp won't get commited at all to git." misleading, since `.gitignore` does not affect on what is to be committed (but staging and other status-alike commands)