# .gitignore file for ssh directory

Tags: git, ssh, gitignore

I am trying to make sure the contents of the .ssh directory do not get into the Git Repository:

**executeS:~$ git diff --stat --cached origin/master**

```
.gitignore           |   7 ------
 .ssh/.gitignore      |   2 ++
 .ssh/authorized_keys |   1 +
 .ssh/id_rsa          |  51 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 .ssh/id_rsa.pub      |   1 +
 .ssh/known_hosts     |   2 ++
 .viminfo             | 123 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------------------------------
```

**I then take them out as follows:**

```
executeS:~$ git rm --cached .ssh/authorized_keys
rm '.ssh/authorized_keys'
executeS:~$ git rm --cached .ssh/id_rsa
rm '.ssh/id_rsa'
executeS:~$ git rm --cached .ssh/id_rsa.pub
rm '.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
executeS:~$ git rm --cached .ssh/known_hosts
```

**I have the following .gitignore file**

```
executeS:~/.ssh$ pwd
/home/dockcclubdjango/.ssh

executeS:~/.ssh$ cat .gitignore
.*
!/.gitignore
```

But then if I do, "git add . -A", I get waht I had in step 1 all over
again. What can I do to make sure that .ssh NEVER gets into the
repository?

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27629812/2008111 ?

Comment: I think the `.gitignore` file must been in the root directory... presuming here that your working directory / root is `~`, and the `.gitignore` files is `~/.ssh/.gitignore`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need also

1. add `/.ssh` line to your `.gitignore`
2. commit all changes (removal of `.ssh` from git and addition of the line to `.gitignore`)

Now `git add -A` will not add it back (tested with Git 2.15.0)

Regarding second question ("What can I do to make sure that .ssh NEVER gets into the repository?"): `.gitignore` does not prevent a file to be added to a repository. You can always add ignored file with `git add -f path/to/file`.