# How can I ignore non dotfiles (all non hidden directories, in the root of my repository) with git ignore?

Tags: git

I'd like to keep track of my "dotfiles". I'd like a git ignore to ignore all hidden files (file extension: **.***).

Essentially the opposite of: [Git: how to ignore hidden directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021441/git-how-to-ignore-hidden-directories)

Within my **.gitignore** I've tried:

`[^.]*`

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Include all dot files.
!.*
```

Both which do not seem to work as intended.

MCVE:

```
mkdir .test .test2
mkdir abc abc2

echo ".keepme" > .test/.keepme
echo ".keepme" > .test2/.keepme
echo ".keepme" > abc/.keepme
echo ".keepme" > abc2/.keepme

echo "keepme" > .test/keepme
echo "keepme" > .test2/keepme
echo "keepme" > abc/keepme
echo "keepme" > abc2/keepme

git init
# attempt 1
echo "[^.]*" > .gitignore

mkdir -p .test/abc/
echo "abc" > .test/abc/abc

git add .gitignore
git commit -m "gitignore"

git add .

git status
```

Comment: Rather than "does not work," please edit your question to include the output of `git status` or other tools whose behavior is surprising you.

Comment: Will add a MCVE tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I wouldn't go for this solution, where you have a `.git` directory in your home directory. I would have a separate, actual repo, and a script to install the dotfiles into your home directory.

Comment: It's actually not recommended to use git to manage files in your home directory. Something like GNU Stow is a better option. It's similar to @root's suggestion but uses symbolic links. See http://brandon.invergo.net/news/2012-05-26-using-gnu-stow-to-manage-your-dotfiles.html

Comment: I'm using the following technique https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles very simple indeed and has been working perfectly for months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to prepend a  `/` to have it act on the root directory only.

```
/[^.]*
```

This question helped: [How to exclude file only from root folder in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637660/how-to-exclude-file-only-from-root-folder-in-git)