# Git - ignore all non-dotfiles

Tags: git, gitignore, dotfiles

I'm trying to figure out a rule for `.gitignore` file to only keep track of my dotfiles.
I've tried combinations of `!.*` and  `!^.*` used after `*` and also  `[^.]*` as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354526/how-can-i-ignore-non-dotfiles-all-non-hidden-directories-in-the-root-of-my-rep). None of those ignored all of the visible, non dotfiles. What am I missing?

Comment: What about `*` followed by `!.*`? This seems to work for me, can you post output from your git status when it includes files you don't want?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't that you're already tracking non-dotfiles?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sorry, typo in my original post. I tried it and it's doing something peculiar. It ignores all non-dotfiles as intended, but also ignores some dot folders, e.g. I have a ```.config``` folder which I'm tracking (but not all the files in it) and now all the untracked files from ```.config```` folder got ignored (I may want to add them later)

Comment: You can always force-add files you want to track even if git is configured to ignore them. Additionally, you can add further rules in .gitignore which makes git un-ignore the files in that folder again. It is, however, not easy to build a few simple rules that does "what I think it should do". The rules are simple, so they do simple things. But you can add more rules.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023985/7976758

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
*
!/**/
!.*
```

Ignore everything, unignore all directories, unignore dotfiles.

Answer (score 1):

- `*` ignores everything
- `!.*` except dot files
- `!.*/**` except any files inside dot files

```
*
!.*
!.*/**
```